# Precedence of __call over __callStatic

Tags: php, function, magic-methods

I noticed that each of the examples below will echo `__call`.

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->something();
        self::something();
        call_user_func(array("self", "something"));
        forward_static_call(array("self", "something"));
        A::something();
        call_user_func(array(__CLASS__, "something"));
        forward_static_call(array(__CLASS__, "something"));
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        echo __FUNCTION__ . "<br />";
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        echo __FUNCTION__ . "<br />";
    }

}

new A();
```

Is it possible to invoke the `__callStatic` method from inside object context, even when a `__call` magic method is present in the class?

I find that `call_user_func(array(__CLASS__, "__callStatic"), array("method"), array());` is somewhat ugly.

Comment: If the call is made from within a static method `__callStatic` will be used. E.g. http://3v4l.org/ca0ER (for some versions at least)

Comment: @Yoshi It's made from within object context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__callStatic()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a **static context**.

But when you did `foo::bar()` from a **non-static context** (in your code, `__construct` method is non-static context) will be a **non-static call**, **unless the function is explicitly defined as static**.

So if you really want to use `__callStatic()` in the `__construct` method, you could use it directly.

```
public function __construct() {
    self::__callStatic('something', array());
}
```

Comment: __callStatic generally helps in handling methods that arent being decalred so why __call again then?